# Importing an XML file to workspace in Matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, structure, xmlreader

I am trying to import an XML file which is around 40MB into Matlab workspace (structure or cells), with the help of a `xml_read` library in MATLAB. For smaller XML files it works without any problems, but as the size of the file I want to use is too big, the MATLAB Program just wont respond. I do not even receive Memory exception Error message. Does any one know an alternative to this problem ?

I also tried to just use the instruction `XMLread` instruction to create a DOM object, but encountered the same Problem.

Here is the link to the library i refer to :

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12907-xml-io-tools

Comment: That is a pretty large XML file. How long did you wait for MATLAB to process it?

Comment: I waited for around 30 minutes or so.. Do you think it might work if I could wait a little longer ?

Comment: That's great! Consider adding an answer below with some details of what you did to help others with a similar issue.

Comment: Hi,Solved this problem by increasing the Java heap memory in Matlab. With help of xml_read, I could import huge XML files to structures in Matlab in minutes

Comment: Ya, I tried to, But unfortunately I do not have Reputation to add an answer :)